# How to Stop Visual Studio from Automatically Updating Dependencies while scaffolding Identity in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a project using asp.net core 3.1, I have to scaffold Identity using Visual Studio 2019. This is the code from .csproj file
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`
All of dependencies have same version that is 3.1.0 but when I try to scaffold Identity visual studio automatically updates `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />` to the latest supported version. I tried updating my project to asp.net 5.0 but then it updates the package to `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />`. This mismatch of versions created by visual studio creates the following error

> There was error an running the selected code generator: 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for [Project Name]

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1dqK.jpg)

I have tried updating all installed packages using NuGet package manager but nothing worked.
How to prevent Visual Studio from updating the dependency before scaffolding?? or how to sync these versions.

[Before Running Scaffolding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UehbJ.jpg)

[After Running Scaffolding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lnI7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> This is the code from .csproj file
> `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` All of dependencies
> have same version that is 3.1.0 but when I try to scaffold Identity
> visual studio automatically updates `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />` to the latest supported version.

Yes, you are right. In Asp.net Core 3.1 application, if we are using Scaffold Identity, it will add the 3.1.5 version Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package. And we could use this version package to generate the Identity page successful. If you still want to use the 3.1.0 version, just change it via the NuGet Package Manger (choose the required version and click the Update button):

[image]

To migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0, first, please make sure you are using [Visual Studio 2019 16.8 or later](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=inline+link&utm_content=download+vs2019)(I suggest you could use the latest version) and [.NET 5.0 SDK or later](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0). More detail information, see [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Then, you should update the target framework from `netcoreapp3.1` to `net5.0`. Code in the  myapplication.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework> 
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup> 
        //...
  </ItemGroup> 
</Project>
```

After that, in the NeGet Package Manager panel, checked the Select All Packages and click the Update button, it will update all packages to the latest version.

[image]

The result as below:

[image]

Finally, if still meet the Package restore failed error, try to update the package one by one. And you could try to change the update order because of the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed answer. Migrating to .NET 5 did not work for me neither did updating the packages in both versions 3.1 and 5.0. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.5 What worked for me is using .NET Core CLI instead of using Visual Studio for scaffolding Identity. 
Did not work for me. 
                         **Add > New Scaffolded Item > Select Identity > Add** 

Following Command worked for me. 
  `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext`

will let know if anything goes wrong again.